# Join lists of different lengths at unequal intervals in python?

Tags: python, list, append

I'm trying to join two lists that have different lengths of data.

```
list1 = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

My desired out put would be something like this:

```
[a12, b34, c56, d78, e910, f1112
```

My first though would be to do something like increment i at different intervals

```
for i in printlist:
    for i in stats:
        print(printlist[i] + stats[i] + stats[i+1])
```

But that spits out `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` and I don't see that working since i would increment incorrectly for both lists.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: try "for i in range(len(printlist))" and the same with stats "for j in range(len(stats))"

Comment: Have fun with "for p, x, y in zip(printlist, stats[::2], stats[1::2]): print(f"{p}{x}{y}")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to code it is to have 2 counters to keep track of indices. One you increment by 1 on each iteration, and the other by 2 on each iteration. This would be done as follows:

```py
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

list3 = []
i = 0
j = 0
while i < len(list1):
  list3.append(list1[i] + str(list2[j]) + str(list2[j+1]))
  i += 1
  j += 2

print(list3)
```

But you'll notice that `j` here is always twice the value of `i` (i.e. `j=2*i`) so there's no point having 2 counters. So you can simplify it this way:

```py
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

list3 = []
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
  list3.append(list1[i] + str(list2[2*i]) + str(list2[2*i + 1]))

print(list3)
```

or as list comprehension:

```py
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

list3 = [list1[i] + str(list2[2*i]) + str(list2[2*i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(list1))]
print(list3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
list1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

list3 = [str(i)+str(j) for i,j in zip(list2[::2], list2[1::2])]
["".join(list(x)) for x in zip(list1, list3)]
```

output

```
['a12', 'b34', 'c56', 'd78', 'e910', 'f1112']
```